# Imagem associada a Tag

Tags: novo-recurso, status-futuro

Poderíamos ter imagem associada a tag, assim como no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) (*note as tags:* android, facebook, mongodb, etc.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Poderemos desde que essas e outras empresas resolvam pagar para aparecer aqui no SOpt também. Elas são tags patrocinadas e uma das formas da empresa Stack Exchange Inc poder bancar todo seu custo ao oferecer a plataforma que utilizamos.

A empresa oferece algumas propagandas gratuitamente para projetos open-source, não sei se isso é válido para tags. Acredito que não, caso contrário, teria em grande parte delas e tornaria essa forma de divulgação menos atraente para os pagantes.

A não ser que o site tenha um sucesso muito grande, não vejo isso acontecendo. Embora possa ser mais fácil vender um pacote global.

Comment: Não notei que estas imagens estavam como patrocínio.